# Display Earth map in Azimuthal Equidistant Projection

Tags: matlab, geography, map-projections, satellite, orbital-mechanics

I have to display the Earth's map in azimuthal equidistant projection, by giving the lattitude and longnitude as input in Matlab. I am using the `eqdazim` projection, but I am still getting the map with point (0,0) in the center. I want to be able to change the point that is the center if the circle map.

```
landareas = shaperead('landareas.shp','UseGeoCoords',true);
axesm ('eqdazim', 'Frame', 'on');
geoshow(landareas);
```

[image]

Also, I don't know how to change the radius of the image. I don't need the circle with the whole Earth but instead something about ~2000km radius around center point.

I need it in order to put its image on a dome. Below is a simple example with such a dome and **random** fragment of the Earth's surface. Keep in mind, that it's just an image that I cropped manually from large Mercator map.

[image]

I was hoping that I can use the Mapping Toolbox in order to get such a map automatically, by giving lattitude, longnitude and radius. I have all necessary data, which is:

- **Lattitude & Longnitude**
- **The radius of the circle**

I just don't know how can I get this part of Earth's map. I think I have to use the [azimuthal equidistant projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection). I just don't know how to do this in MATLAB/Mapping Toolbox.

Comment: Did you plot the second figure yourself? That is not azimuthal equidistant, if you really need what is displayed in second figure.

Comment: @saastn Yes, I already know. I will edit and anserw whole question myself soon.